# Java recursion return only if not null

Tags: java, recursion

This is pure play and fun I wrote a binary search tree from scratch I want to use a recursive function that searches the tree for a given value for now its just an int but later I want to return an object. The issue if the value is null it returns null so when I call the SearchTree function it will return null before it returns the actual value. The only way around this is to return an array with the matching value is there a more elegant way?

```
public class BinaryNode implements BaseNode{
    private BinaryNode right;
    private BinaryNode left;
    private int data;
    //...

    public BinaryNode traverseTree(int Data){
    if (getData() == Data){
        return this;
    }
    else if (Data < getData() && getLeft() != null){
        getLeft().traverseTree(Data);
    }
    else if(Data > getData() && getRight() != null){
        getRight().traverseTree(Data);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably accept ShroudedKnife's answer but stylistically I would write it like:

```
public class BinaryNode implements BaseNode{
    private BinaryNode right;
    private BinaryNode left;
    private int data;
    //...

    public BinaryNode traverseTree(int Data){
        final BinaryNode rvalue;
        if (getData() == Data){
            rvalue = this;
        }
        else if (Data < getData() && getLeft() != null){
            rvalue = getLeft().traverseTree(Data);
        }
        else if(Data > getData() && getRight() != null){
            rvalue = getRight().traverseTree(Data);
        }
        else {
            rvalue = null;
        }
        return rvalue;
    }
}
```

I prefer only having one return statement and the above also looks more like `let` FP pattern matching (the `final BinaryNode` will require the variable be set so it almost forms an expression.

Also you should know that this is called augmentative recursion or head recursion. Tail recursion is preferred in most FP languages as the compiler/runtime optimizes for it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the value from the recursive call.

Try this:

```
public class BinaryNode implements BaseNode{
    private BinaryNode right;
    private BinaryNode left;
    private int data;
    //...

    public BinaryNode traverseTree(int Data){
    if (getData() == Data){
        return this;
    }
    else if (Data < getData() && getLeft() != null){
        return getLeft().traverseTree(Data);
    }
    else if(Data > getData() && getRight() != null){
        return getRight().traverseTree(Data);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Totally answers the question but the explanation and single return statement from Adam Gent I feel is more elegant. Many thanks anyways